# Screen brightness hotkey stopped working with Ubuntu 16.10 (ASUS TP200SA-UHBF)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness, asus, backlight

I'm slowly working through all the defects on a plain-vanilla Ubuntu 16.10 install on this machine but this one has me stumped.  My screen brightness hotkeys, Fn-F5 and Fn-F6, worked fine on Ubuntu 16.04 but now that I've done a clean install of Ubuntu 16.10 they don't work.

Here's what I know:

- screen brightness is addressable by the kernel (`/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/`), desktop tools such as Redshift and adjusting brightness with the slider in the config panel works fine, as does command-line adjusting: `echo 1000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`
- I can see them in `evtest` in the listing for the device "Asus WMI Hotkeys" ("Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)" and "Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)"), however *pressing the keys doesn't generate key events*.
- The keys *do* work in the BIOS and in GRUB, but once the kernel starts the key events don't seem to be seen.
- I've tried kernel params "acpi_osi=", "acpi_osi=Linux", "acpi_osi=Windows" with no luck (although that definitely disabled some stuff, according to `evtest`)

I know this worked under Linux because it worked under Ubuntu 16.04.  Any suggestions for my next debugging step?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you fin something?

Comment: I didn't.  I kept digging until it started to look like a systemd problem, and spending weeks in that nightmare trying to figure it out didn't seem worth the effort.  I managed to get by with a combination of RedShift with the settings WAY down and the occasional manual nudge in the control panel.

Comment: The last thing I found it was when I run evtest I did see an event called Asus WMI Hotkeys and the keycodes were in this event like you. But nothing more :(

Comment: Finally I installed Ubuntu gnome with kernel 4.10 and every works fine.